# How can I use a third party Class Object as Hashmap Key?

Tags: java, oop, hashmap

OK I understand the working of equals and hashcode and How they are used in hashmap.
But This question crossed my mind What if I am having a third party object which does'nt have overridden hashcode and equals and I am not even allowed to modify it.

Consider following Class:

```
//Unmodifiable class
public final class WannaBeKey{

    private String id;

    private String keyName;

    //Can be many more fields

    public String getId()
    {
          return id;
    }

    public String getKeyName()
    {
          return id;
    }
    //no hashcode or equals :(

  }
```

Now I want to make this class as my Hashmap key obviously it won't work without equals and hashcode. I want to know is there any way to handle such cases? I am unable to think of any or I am way over my head..

Thanks.

Comment: It does have an equals and a hashCode - the ones of `Object`.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not always good enough, he may need equality based on the id of the WannaBeKey, not the instance

Comment: But they will fail in hashmap because Objects equals method will do reference equality check not the content equality.

Comment: If the ones from Object are not sufficient, then you'll probably have to create a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_Pattern).

Comment: @JasonNichols true, but still the class does not have "no" equals and hashCode.

Comment: Make the key to your map the id string.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thats just one field what if I have more fields?

Comment: then either you go with the wrapper or have a function that concatenates the fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've encountered this previously, and worked around it by creating a wrapper for the WannaBeKey as such:

```
public class WannaBeKeyWrapper {

  private final WannaBeKey key;


  public WannaBeKeyWrapper(WannaBeKey key) {
    this.key = key;
  } 

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    // Insert equality based on WannaBeKey
  }

  public int hashCode() {
    // Insert custom hashcode in accordance with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()
  }
}
```

Obviously this changes your `Set` from `Set<WannaBeKey>` to `Set<WannaBeKeyWrapper>`, but you should be able to account for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a wrapper for that object which will have the overridden methods. Then you can use the wrapper class as the key of your hash map.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's the only way to use ``WannaBeKey`` as the base for a map key.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the actual object in another instance with the required semantics:

```
class KeyWrapper {

  WannaBeKey key; // constructor omitted

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return key.getId().hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    // equals method implementation
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply extend the class (if the class was not `final` as you stated in your edit).

Comment: The class is also final, so cannot extend it.

Comment: Then use the wrapper approach as I mentioned to be the better solution anyways.

Comment: I am not the OP though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered thoroughly but I thought it was worth mentioning that the solutions above are part of a specific design pattern known as a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

The [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or Wrapper pattern uses essentially the same solution but is meant more for transforming code to a different interface whereas Decorator is used for extension.